# Table/Matrix/Array with no space between cells and all same size

Tags: tables, spacing

I have several graphics like objects(tikzpictures) I would like to put in a matrix like configuration. I've been using multicols but I can't seem to figure out how to set the cells to all be the same size.

When I try tabular or array the cells have to large spacing/padding and it causes a non-matrix like configuration(it wraps some rows).

How can I create a simple 4x4 matrix where all cells are of the same size which is equal to the size of the largest cell AND no extra spacing between the cells(my objects already have the necessary spacing... although I might need/want to manually add a little extra).

Comment: have you tried using `minipage`s? something like `\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}...`

Comment: @cmhughes I've thought about it but haven't tried, I'll look over it and try to come up with a solution...

Answer (score 3):

If the objects *do* have all the same size, then

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}c@{}}
<object 1> & <object 2> \\
<object 3> & <object 3>
\end{tabular}
```

will do.